Get list of "called" VBA procedures within all code modules in an Excel's workbook's project
I have several dozen VBA code modules that I have created over the years.
Most of these code modules are self-contained (i.e., they are NOT dependent on any subroutines or functions contained in other VBA code modules).
However, for the few code modules that do make "calls" to functions in other code modules, is there a way (using VBA and the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 library) to get of list of those "called" procedures?
For example, below are two VBA code modules and their associated VBA procedures (very simplistic):



Module Name
Procedure Name
Dependency on Other Module




Module1
Sub Foo
Makes a call to Moo


Module1
Function Boo
Makes a call to Doo


Module1
Function Koo
None


Module2
Sub Roo
None


Module2
Function Moo
Makes a call to Koo


Module2
Function Doo
Makes a call to Boo



The output I'm seeking should look like the following:



Module Name
Procedure Name
Called Procedure
Contained in Module




Module1
Sub Foo
Function Moo
Module2


Module1
Function Boo
Function Doo
Module2


Module2
Function Moo
Function Koo
Module1


Module2
Function Doo
Function Boo
Module1



I have tried searching for one or more APIs within the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 library that can get the modules/methods that are called by a method, but to date, I haven't found any.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

What happened to all the previous comments that were posted here?

While it won't produce the exact table you are looking for (hence not adding this as an 'answer'), you can use VBE_Extras to get this information. It has a feature to get 'Declarations' that are 'Referenced from other Modules in this Project'. For each Declaration, you can then get all of its References which will include the Module (as well as the Sub/Function/Property of the reference). To be clear: I am the developer of VBE_Extras which is a paid-for tool but comes with a 60 day free trial.

Thanks, John, for the info regarding VBE Extras.  I will go to your site and check it out.
